# How do you serialize a web control? [edit] how do I serialize a function?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In a web project I'm working on, I need to display 3 list of objects (`Employee`, `Owner`, and `TradeReference`) using dynamic controls.  Those 3 classes extend the class `DataEntry`.  I have 3 separate display functions that look like this:

```
protected void DisplayEmployees()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count; i++)
    {
        Employee emp = employees[i];
        emp.DisplaySelf(i, EmployeeDisplayPanel);

    }//end for
}//end CreateDynamicEmployeeContols()


protected void DisplayOwners()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < owners.Count; i++)
    {
        Owner own = owners[i];
        own.DisplaySelf(i, OwnerDisplayPanel);

    }//end for
}//end CreateDynamicOwnerContols()


protected void DisplayTradeRefs()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tradeRefs.Count; i++)
    {
        TradeReference tRef = tradeRefs[i];
        tRef.DisplaySelf(i, TradeRefDisplayPanel);

    }//end for
}//end CreateDynamicTradeRefContols()
```

This solution has code duplication, so I created a generic class`DisplayableList` which extends `List`.  `DisplayableList` holds a reference to a `Panel` and has a {get} method for it, otherwise, it's identical to `List`.  Now my code looks like this:

```
 [Serializable]
public class DisplayableList<T> : List<T>
{
    private Panel display;

    public DisplayableList(ref Panel display)
    {
        this.display = display;

    }//end constructor

    public Panel Display
    {
        get
        {
            return this.display;

        }//end get
    }//end Display

}//end class


//on Web Page
{
...

    protected void DisplayList(DisplayableList<DataEntry> list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            DataEntry entry = list[i];
            entry.DisplaySelf(i, list.Display);

        }//end for
    }//end DisplayList()               ...ext...    }//end Page
```

This should work, but I get a run time error because Panel is not serialize.  How  do I serialize a web control?  If that isn't possible, how can I implement a solution that doesn't have code duplication or break encapsulation (a design pattern maybe)?

## Edit

I've given up on serializing a panel, because I'm going to have to de-serialize it at some point which is way to much trouble.

I tried replacing the stored `Panel` in my `DisplayableList` class with a function that returns a panel:

```
public class DisplayableList<T> : List<T>
{
    private Func<Panel> getDisplay;

    public DisplayableList(Func<Panel> func)
    {
        this.getDisplay = func;
    }// end constuctor

    public Panel Display
    {
        get
        {
            return getDisplay();
        }//end get
    }//end Display

}//end class
```

The function that will be stored is a simple get method:

```
public Panel GetEmployeeDisplayPanel()
{
    return EmpDisplayPanel;
}
```

I still get a serialization exception though.  Is serializing a function (that is defined on a content page) any easier than serializing a `Panel` and how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [[Serializable]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33296/Serialization-and-De-serialization) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/328547) you have some in-depth documentation and tutorials on how to use it